# legislating authority

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading an article from Economist, and it talks about "The uncanny", a 1919 essay written by Sigmund Freud. The uncanny effect arises when the subject identifies with someone else..so that he is in doubt to which self he is.

The writer says in a following paragraph that Freud is still the **"legislating authority"**.

I know that legislating authority is the institution which writes laws.

so can I read it as his theory is still the foundation of similar theories in this field or even still the most authorative one?

Comment: It's a cute way of saying that Freud's views on the topic still dominate the field, as if they constituted a set of laws.

Comment: "reference authority" is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read it as his theory is still the most authoritative one. It implies a more extreme amount of non-deviation from his writings than just creating a foundation implies.